# Add project on outer level as dependency to module

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle

I have a project that looks something like this:

```
mainProject/
    mainModule
proj1/
    module1
proj2/
    module2
```

and what I'm trying to do is add `proj1` and `proj2` as dependencies to `mainProject`. I've gotten it to the point where I can import classes from the projects and everything seems to work fine (no "can't resolve symbol" errors), but as soon as I build the project, I get a bunch of errors like:

> Gradle: error: package com.domain.proj1 does not exist
>
> Gradle: error: cannot find symbol class Class1

in classes that when I open them, I can navigate to declarations, see usages, and see no red writing!

When I added the `proj1` and `proj2` modules to the project and started using them, Intellij even suggested adding the dependency to the different projects. The thing I think is odd though is that these changes to dependencies aren't reflected anywhere in my `mainModule`'s `build.gradle` file.

I've been looking for hours for a solution, and I have looked at a bunch of other questions here on Stack Overflow, and would really appreciate an answer.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add dependencies in the 'build.gradle' of your MainProject, like this:

```
compile project(':proj1')
compile project(':proj2')
```

**EDIT:**

And in the 'settings.gradle' this:

```
include ':proj1' 
project(':proj1').projectDir = new File('../proj1') 

include ':proj2' 
project(':proj2').projectDir = new File('../proj2')
```

Comment: the problem is that statement looks for the `proj1` and `proj2` underneath the `mainProj` directory. These aren't in the same directory